# Flutter how to exchange info between devices on wi fi

Tags: android, flutter, server, wifi

So im building a new app where i require a player to open a hotspot and other players connect to it.
Then they can exchange information and the views changes between players based on the game state.
Its like server / client in ue4.
how can i approuch this in flutter ?!

Answer (score 1):

You can use p2p packages like

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nearby_connections

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_p2p/versions

From which you can pass data from one device to another. Create json model for each data type and broadcast it to all connected players. Then based on logic let the relevant player id play