Flutter app to sync data between phone and PC
Is there a way to be able to sync data between phone's Flutter app and PC?
Say you have a music library with tags, ratings, etc. You may edit it on phone or pc. Are there any packages or methods to be able to sync phone and PC libraries, when they are in single Wifi network or something?

Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73517148/flutter-how-to-exchange-info-between-devices-on-wi-fi
